# Python multiprocessing never joins

Tags: python, multithreading, process, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using `multiprocessing`, and specifically a `Pool` to spin off a couple of 'threads' to do  a bunch of slow jobs that I have. However, for some reason, I can't get the main thread to rejoin, even though all of the children appear to have died.

***Resolved: It appears the answer to this question is to just launch multiple `Process` objects, rather than using a `Pool`. It's not abundantly clear why, but I suspect the remaining process is a manager for the pool and it's not dying when the processes finish. If anyone else has this problem, this is the answer.***

---

**Main Thread**

```
pool = Pool(processes=12,initializer=thread_init)
for x in xrange(0,13):
    pool.apply_async(thread_dowork)
pool.close()
sys.stderr.write("Waiting for jobs to terminate\n")
pool.join()
```

*The `xrange(0,13)` is one more than the number of processes because I thought I had an off by one, and one process wasn't getting a job, so wasn't dying and I wanted to force it to take a job. I have tried it with 12 as well.*

**Multiprocessing Functions**

```
def thread_init():
    global log_out
    log_out = open('pool_%s.log'%os.getpid(),'w')
    sys.stderr = log_out
    sys.stdout = log_out
    log_out.write("Spawned")
    log_out.flush()
    log_out.write(" Complete\n")
    log_out.flush()


def thread_dowork():
    log_out.write("Entered function\n")
    log_out.flush()
    #Do Work
    log_out.write("Exiting ")
    log_out.flush()
    log_out.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The output of the logfiles for all 12 children is:

```
Spawned
Complete
Entered function
Exiting
```

The main thread prints 'Waiting for jobs to terminate', and then just sits there.

`top` shows only one copy of the script (the main one I believe). `htop` shows two copies, one of which is the one from top, and the other one of which is something else. Based on its PID, it's none of the children either.

Does anyone know something I don't?

Comment: Why do you have the `sys.exit(0)` there? Just let the function return.

Comment: I was attempting to make sure they all exited, because of this very issue. I've tried it without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have an answer but I read the docs for Apply_async and it seems counter to your stated problem...

> Callbacks should complete immediately since otherwise the thread which
>   handles the results will get blocked.

I'm not familiar with the Pool but it seems to me that your use-case could easily be handled by this recipe on [Python Module of the Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html)

Comment: Right... `apply_async` should do exactly what I want. Pools are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), but I'll give the `Process` method a shot because the `Pool` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm going to give you the nod for the answer, because it seems that switching everything over to `Process` rather than using `Pool` fixed the issue. I'm still not exactly sure why that is, but it works now.

Comment: Thanks - I try to use the least complicated method that I can find to solve problems... Maybe I'll dive into Pool... one day :-)