# Why does my multiprocess Python script never end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I try some multiprocess examples, mainly : http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/ where I have taken the 'simple application', which use multiprocess to test URLs. 
When I use it (in Python 3.3, on Windows in PyCharm IDE) with some modifications, with a lot of URLs, my script never stop, and I don't see why.

```
import httplib2
import sys
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process

def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    for url in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        try:
            print("In : %s - %s." % (current_process().name, url))
            status_code = print_site_status(url)
            done_queue.put("%s - %s got %s." % (current_process().name, url, status_code))
        except:
            done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, url, str(sys.exc_info()[0])))
    print("Out : %s " % (current_process().name))
    return True

def print_site_status(url):
    http = httplib2.Http(timeout=10)
    headers, content = http.request(url)
    return headers.get('status', 'no response')

def main():
    workers = 8
    work_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    with open("Annu.txt") as f: # file with URLs
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for surl in lines:
        work_queue.put(surl)

    for w in range(workers):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        work_queue.put('STOP')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print("END")
    done_queue.put('STOP')

    for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I well see all the URLs status tested, and all the process 'Out' message that indicate hte end of the process, but never my 'END' message.
A list of URLs I use is : http://www.pastebin.ca/2946850 .

So ... where is my error ? Is it a duplicate with : [Python multiprocessing threads never join when given large amounts of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208472/python-multiprocessing-threads-never-join-when-given-large-amounts-of-work?rq=1) ?

Some informations : when I suppress 'done_queue' everywhere in the code : it's works.

Comment: Note that END will not be printed at the END as you think. Scroll up close to halfway and you will see it there.

Comment: @dopstar Sorry but I your comment is not clear, do you say that 'END' message is not at the end of script ? If Yes : I know, 'END' is here to say that processes are ended.

Comment: You are also printing out the status from the done queue after you printed END so this places END roughly midway. You have 500+ urls so you will have 1k+ print outs with END somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I have confirmed that this prints out END somewhere in the middle. Check the output of your script after I ran it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10501008/ . END is at line 553.

Comment: @dopstar I saw your printing (thx for it !) and the result is OK for me : the 'END' message is after the 'Out : Process-x' ones (and before the 'Process-x - http://xxxxx' ones) . But, in my case the,  'Out : Process-x' messages are the last ! no 'END' one : I have (+/-) 500 prints not 1000. May be a Windows configuration issue...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer (in the Python doc : https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming  ) :

> Warning As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a
>   queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then
>   that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been
>   flushed to the pipe.

So change the code :

```
    print("Out : %s " % (current_process().name))
    return True
```

By :

```
    print("Out : %s " % (current_process().name))
    done_queue.cancel_join_thread()
    return True
```

I don't understand why the initial code works with small quantity of URLs...

Answer (score 0):

From the `Queue` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects):

> If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

That means your loops never terminate.

You either need to add a timeout to the `get` and stop the loop if your get the `Empty` exception or you need to exit the loop when you get the `STOP` message.

Comment: Sure, a small number of URLS works. I use processes just to learn. I tested with some logging and it seems that all URLs are processed BUT the process seemed not to join.

Comment: Add `print` statements around the join to see which process doesn't come back. And how did you check that each URL is processed? The naked eye can't check 1000 URLs.

Comment: I tested that all URLs where processed and all  'print("Out : %s " % (current_process().name))' lines done. It seems that ALL the processes doesn' t come bacK

Comment: I think they are waiting for you to read their stdout. You use `print` in the processes. That means they write to stdout.

Comment: I don't think : I added 'print' to trace, AFTER the problem occured.

Comment: Do you see that output anywhere?

Comment: Sure, all the prints of the processes are seen.

Comment: Or not ... `blocks` is `False` in your case, you should get an `Empty` exception. Why don't you see that one?

Comment: Hey ! Your edited answer changed the game. As I said the 'queue' seemed the origin of the problem and it seems you have a good answer to fix it. I test ASAP and come back.